# Java: How to merge two .txt files into one?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

For this program, I have to merge two files, one which contains student names and ID numbers, and the other which contains class ID codes. I must then match the ID code with students to the ID codes of classes and alphabetically sort them into a new class roster.

I have to use arrays and binary searching.

I'm just really unsure of how to do it. I don't have much, but what I do have is this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MergingFiles {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
    Scanner studentFile = new Scanner(new File("students.txt"));
    Scanner classFile = new Scanner(new File("classes.txt"));

    while (studentFile.hasNext()){
     }
    while (classFile.hasNext()){
     }
      //as long as another line, keeps running
      //sort students alphabetically
      //2 substrings, one id #, one students
      //read id codes, match with name
      //create new roster file


  }



}
```

I know I need to put the contents into an array, but what kind of array and how would I write this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you covered so far? Objects? Two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Yes. We've covered those, along with Reader, Writer, and Buffered Reader and Writer.

Comment: can you post a brief sample of the format of both files?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1.) Create a `Student` class with variables `name` and `id`

2.) When scanning the list of students add them to a `Student[]`. Arrays can't be resized (and it seems you're not allowed to use lists), so think about how you'll know how large to make the array so that you don't have to resize it (unless you want to add code to resize the array on the fly, which is also do-able).

3.) Sort the `Student[]` (requirement of binary searching). If you have to do this manually then you'll have to write your own sort implementation (think about which field of the `Student` object you're going to be comparing). If you're allowed to use the API [sort methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object[],%20int,%20int%29) (and you have covered interfaces), then just make `Student` implement `Comparable` then call `Arrays.sort`.

4.) When scanning through the classes file, I assume you'll need to use binary searching here to find the `Student` (based on their id), but I'm not sure of the format of the input files so I'm not sure I can give you too much more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 public static File mergeAllFiles(File[]files,File dest) throws IOException{
    List<String> paths = 
   Stream.of(files).map(File::getPath).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (String string : paths) {
        List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(string));
        Files.write(Path.of(dest.getPath()),allLines, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
    return dest;
}
```